# Numerical method to plot a second order diferential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions

I want to plot the equation that show in the first image by code
the plot is given in a book.
[image: Equation and plot]

Is easy plot interactive in first order derivate equations, like lorentz atractor, by increase just a bit and evaluate, but have not idea what methods follow to do the plot in this case

### UPDATE

If the equation was dϕ/ds+sin ϕ= 0
I plot doing the follow:

```
Define a constant ds=0.01 

Init s, ϕ to some value
Repeat for n interactions :
dϕ=- ds*sin dϕ
ϕ=  ϕ+dϕ
s=s+ds
plot(s, ϕ)
```

the image belows show my code for plot Lorenz´s atractor in Blender with python
[image]

Comment: Do you want to solve the differential equation and then plot that solution as a function of $s$ or a phase portrait which doesn't solve the equation, but shows the qualitative behaviors better.

Comment: If you know how to solve first-order *systems* of ODEs, it is easy to solve higher-order ODEs by introducing new variables for the unknown derivatives: see [reduction of order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinary_differential_equation#Reduction_of_order). In this case, you'll have $d\phi/ds = \phi_1, d\phi_1/ds = \sin\phi$. However, this probably won't give you the plot shown here. It seems maybe the ODE is supposed to give the [Whewell equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whewell_equation) of the given curve.

Comment: It is quite improbable that this is a plot of the pendulum equation, which usually has boring periodical solutions. You would need to give more details on what the book uses to get that plot.

Comment: @ Lutzl Chaos for engineers of Tomasz Kapitaniak, say spatial plots of this equation, i want to test by myself

Comment: Your code is for the symplectic Euler and Euler method, both have order 1. It does not explain what this has to do with the image you want to get. Which variables are along the axes?

Comment: @ Lutzl I want to do the same, I dont know that this is the Euler method, I do the code aproximation , infered by the definition of differentiation. But not understand a simple way to do the same aproximation to second order differentiation

Comment: if I interact with a increment of ds or second ds dont know how to aproximate the rest of the values